# How to select part of string from JSONPath value?

Tags: json, xpath, soapui, jsonpath

My element is called: `$.long_message`

It contains the value: SessionKey:e0db06e773a9f6d04e52486dc40f6647

I need to remove: SessionKey:

I know if this was Xpath, I could use: `substring-after($.long_message,':')`
Is there something like this for JSONPath?

Comment: Where are you trying to do this? In `groovy` test step in soapui? In property-transfer?

Comment: @albciff I was trying to do this in a property-transfer.  I added my work around above.

Comment: Your workaround seems fine. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: The work around is fine.  I'll mark this question as resolved.

Comment: In SO you preferably answer your own question and picking that answer as your preferred answer instead of *marking it as resolved*.

Comment: On StackOverflow we do not put "Resolved" in the subject. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround:

In soapui I set the property dropdown to ResponseAsXml and the Path language dropdown to XPath. Then added the sub-string function like this:

```
declare namespace ns1='https://api.example.com/thing/v2/start';
substring-after(//ns1:Response[1]/ns1:long_message[1],':')
```